# Bucket policy to prevent bucket delete except by a specific role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am looking for a bucket policy which restricts all users/roles to delete specific bucket and allows only root account user and a specific role to delete the bucket. something like below. Please suggest.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "PutObjBucketPolicy",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Prevent bucket delete",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": *,
        "Action": "s3:DeleteBucket",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket-s3"
        "Condition"
            StringNotEquals:
                { "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AWS-account-ID:role/role-name" }
    }
]
```

}